# Storing Data in Database without Tables (Because I don't need Entities/Objects) Django Models class

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, class, django-models

Let me Explain the Whole Question Correctly.
I have a class called **CData** and I just want to store 6 values in it.
I don't want different instances/Objects of it because it is global data that is not related to its instances i.e. Its static and should be accessed only by Class itself *No objects are to be created.*

`Model.py`

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Patient(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    dob = models.DateField()
    fever = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cough = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    headache = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    diarrhea = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    diarrhea = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tasteless = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CovidPatient(models.Model):
    
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name


class CData:
    total = 0
    covid = 0
    treatment = 0
    recovered = 0
    dead = 0
    discharged = 0

    def total_patient(self):
        self.total = len(Patient.objects.all())
        return self.total
    
    def add_patient(self, pid):
        patient = CovidPatient.objects.get_or_create(id = pid)
        self.covid += 1
        return patient.name

    def covid_patient(self):
        return self.covid

    def under_treatment(self):
        self.treatment = len(CovidPatient.objects.all())
        return self.treatment
    
    def add_recovered(self, cpid):
        patient = CovidPatient.objects.get(id = cpid)
        self.recovered += 1
        patient.delete()

    def total_recovered(self):
        return self.recovered

    def add_dead(self, cpid):
        patient = CovidPatient.objects.get(id = cpid)
        self.dead += 1
        patient.delete()

    def total_dead(self):
        return self.dead

    def add_discharged(self, cpid):
        patient = CovidPatient.objects.get(id = cpid)
        self.discharged += 1
        patient.delete()

    def total_discharged(self):
        return self.discharged
```

But the whole problem is I don't know how to achieve it.
If you can see **CData class**, you will realize it should not have any instances, but this data needs to be saved in *Database* of Django.
But the issue is *We don't need a Whole model for it*, for the same reason that we don't need instances or objects of this class.

I am a noob so, I don't know what are exact terms I should search for or how to exactly achieve it.

> To store Data of **CData** class without making a model and How to
> create this a static/Global class that does not need objects to access
> data.

Comment: read up on "singleton" pattern https://www.google.com/search?q=django+model+singleton

Comment: I guess that's not what is needed here ! Or If you can then please brief it

Comment: you say you don't need any instances of the data but how would you access it if there are 0 instances of the data, I believe you need a single instance of the data i.e. a singleton